# Result field dependent oparand

Tags: mysql

I have an application where the user can set operands and values, like,

"If person's age > 21"

consider this a entry in a table `rule`:

```
subject    | operator | operand
-----------+----------+--------
age        | gt       | 21
haircolor  | eq       | brown
```

On the other hand, I have a table like `personproperty`,

```
subject    | value
-----------+------
age        | 21
haircolor  | blonde
```

In my application I will JOIN these together using `subject`; like, I want to find the rules which match for a given user.

Since the `operator` can vary, I would need to somehow tackle that when querying. Is there something possible which is smarter than

```
WHERE
  (
      (rule.operator = 'gt' AND personproperty.value >  rule.operand)
   OR (rule.operator = 'ge' AND personproperty.value >= rule.operand)
   OR (rule.operator = 'lt' AND personproperty.value <  rule.operand)
[... yougettheidea ...]
```

?

Thanks for your input and advice!

Comment: You could use your data to generate dynamic SQL, which you would run with a `prepare` statement.

Comment: what data, and dynamic SQL, would that be? I can't see more dynamically than the five variations of the operand?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can generate a prepare statement more easily if you store symbol directly in your table.

Like 'eq' as '=' , gt as '>' etc ...

You have to create procedure inorder to make use of prepared statement

```
 declare i_count integer ;
    declare i integer default 0;
    declare sub varchar(45) ;
    declare opr varchar(45);

      drop temporary table if exists temp_tbl;
      create temporary table  temp_tbl
      (
      sub varchar(50),
      value varchar(50)
      );


      select count(*) into i_count  from rule;

       while i < i_count do



    select a.subject as s,concat(a.operator," '",a.operand,"'") as value into sub,opr
    from rule a
    order by subject
    limit i,1   ;



    set @sql = concat("insert into temp_tbl select * from personproperty b where b.subject  = '",
    sub ,"' and b.value ", opr) ;



         prepare stmt from  @sql;
         execute stmt;
        deallocate prepare stmt;
     set i = i+ 1;

  end while ;


  select * from temp_tbl ;
```

Comment: by that example, where does `rule.operator` come from? TBH I don't know much about prepared statements, but I don't understand how this will / should work...

Comment: @AdrianFöder . . . I think the intention is that you store the operators as `<`, `>`, or whatever -- the actual operators -- and then construct the query statement as a string.

Comment: hm... maybe what I wonder is, and, as said, I have not much knowledge about prepared statements; the ``rule.operator`` would change with each recordset. Does this reflect that?

I mean, would the rule.operator of the statement represent the actual state of any "current" record?

Comment: If you store the symbols directly then you can pass it into the prepared statement as values directly instead of adding OR conditions every time. I have shown a procedure which does that.

Answer (score 0):

It might be tricky to have just one query that processes all this, since there could be a large number of rules.

You might have more luck if you generated a SQL WHERE clause based on the contents of these rules.  Your WHERE clause could potentially offer greater flexibility, too, so that you an have series of operators.

Comment: it could be a large number of rules, true; but the amount of possible operators is limited: it's only 5 (if I got this right :-p) eq, gt, gte, lt, lte

So, how would such a generated WHERE clause look like? I would generate it, but the flexibility is not on the client's side (which I would use as query data driver), but on the Rules side which I don't know yet. I don't know which operator I can expect there...

Comment: Would there be a large number of Properties, e.g. 'age', 'haircolour', etc?  If so, that could mean 5 terms per property, leading to many terms in total.  Perhaps even a larger number if you permit 'Age > 25 and Age < 30' or similar.